# Send a value set in chrome.storage from an options page to a content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, storage

At a high level, I want a user to toggle the background color of a page. I need the user to do so by clicking a button on the options page. I want the background color to take effect immediately.

At a low level, I understand that I need to send a message from the options page to the content script, reading, and writing settings to `chrome.storage`. However, no message passing I've tried works.

I've read that, to get a message to the content script from the options page, I need the background script to act as an intermediary. I can't get that to work, either.

In order to make my example clearer, I've removed all message passing code from all the example files below.

### `manifest.json`

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Change Background Color",
  "short_name": "Change Background Color",
  "author": "The Author",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "version_name": "1.0",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Change the background color of a page."
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "js": ["content.js"]
  }],
  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "unlimitedStorage",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "http://*/",
    "https://*/",
    "*://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

### `options.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Options</title>
</head>
<body>
   <button id="toggle-background-color">Toggle Background Color</button>
   <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### `options.js`

```js
var toggle = false;

function saveOptions() {
    toggle = !toggle;

    chrome.storage.sync.set(
        {
            toggleBackgroundColor: toggle
        },
        function () {}
    );
}

function retrieveOptions() {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(
        {
            toggleBackgroundColor: false
        },
        function () {}
    );
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', retrieveOptions);
document.getElementById('toggle-background-color').addEventListener('click', saveOptions);
```

### `content.js`

```js
chrome.storage.sync.get(
    {
        toggleBackgroundColor: true
    },
    function(settings) {
        if (true === settings.toggleBackgroundColor) {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
        } else {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
    }
);
```

### `background.js`

```
// This file is thus far empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send a message.  Changing the value in `chrome.storage.local` is sufficient.  All you need to do is be listening for changes using [`chrome.storage.onChanged`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#event-onChanged) in your content script.

You could change your content script to something like:

*content.js*:

```js
function updatePage(){
    chrome.storage.sync.get(
        {
            toggleBackgroundColor: true
        },
        function(settings) {
            if (true === settings.toggleBackgroundColor) {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            } else {
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            }
        }
    );
}
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(updatePage);
updatePage();
```

Note: You could directly use the changed value that is passed to the `storage.onChnaged` listener. However, in this simple example, that just adds complexity when you already have code that is getting the data you need from `chrome.storage.local`. If you are doing more things than just changing the background color, optimizing to not redo everything may be a better solution.

Comment: `@Makyen`, your suggestion worked perfectly. Many thanks.